# win32com.client - SendKeys() not sending backets

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, automation

i am using win32com for windows automation, i am trying to SendKeys to some application, but it is not sending backets
Example: (trying to send)

```
name = "Jayesh (Nick Name)"
shell.SendKeys(name)
```

expected output :

```
Jayesh (Nick Name)
```

but output is

```
Jayesh Nick Name
```

How this can be solved ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the application? I assume it has focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose brackets into braces to get it working:

```
shell.SendKeys("Jayesh {(}Nick Name{)}")
```

Comment: i am reading text from multiple file using loo[ and sending it to vb based windows application (Input Box), number of brackets are also not fixed. line number is fixed which contain brackets.

Comment: You can escape brackets by replacing them in the file content `filte_content.replace('(','{(}').replace(')','{)}')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following `send_keys()` function. This will automatically convert your text to be suitable for use with the function.

```
import time
import win32api
import win32com.client

def send_keys(text):
    for src, dst in [('{', '['), ('}', ']'), ('(', '{(}'), (')','{)}'), ('+', '{+}'), ('^', '{^}'), (r'%', r'{%}'), ('~', '{~}')]:
        text = text.replace(src, dst)
    shell.SendKeys(text)

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("notepad")
time.sleep(1)
shell.AppActivate("Notepad")
send_keys(r"Testing + ^ % ~ ()  +/- {")
```

The plus sign `+`, caret `^`, percent sign `%`, tilde `~`, and parentheses `( )` all need to be wrapped in curly brackets.

Curly brackets themselves also need to be wrapped, but unfortunately there appears to be a problem in Python when trying to send these, resulting in a `pywintypes.com_error` exception. As a result, the function avoids this by converting the characters to square brackets `[ ]`.

Comment: perfect :) Tank you @Martin Evans